# NullPointerException when using a Factory Pattern

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, factory-pattern

I am using a Factory pattern in my Java code.  The factory makes use of an abstract CSVHeader class.  CSVHeader has one abstract and several concrete method.  The header creates one of two inheriting classes (Called TypeOne and TypeTwoHeader below).  These classes have their own version of the one abstract method.

I'm trying to use the Eclipse debugger but I am stumped because the debugger doesn't even get to the first line in the getHeader() method -- the debugger jumps right from the calling class to the NullPointerException class.  Here's the output from the exception:

```
Eclipse java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.package.StationWriter.<init>(StationWriter.java:98)
...
```

I am wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior in Eclipse or when using a factory pattern in Java? Do the angle brackets around `<init>` implicate it's a problem with the way I'm using or not using Generics?  I am using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149.   Here's more about my implementation:

The HeaderFactory's getHeader() method returns one of the subclasses that inherit from CSVHeader; which subclass is returned depends on the input variables.  This method has never had a problem and it still works.  It only breaks when I call it from a the StationWriter class, which calls it in exactly the same way, just with different arguments. The arguments are never read because the code goes right to NullPointerException before it even enters the body of the getHeader() method.

StationWriter (concrete implementation of interface CSVWriter) -- this shows line 98 and is broken:

```
new StationWriter(params) {
   ...
   CSVHeader headerWriter = new HeaderFactory().getHeader(params);
}
```

DeviceWriter (concrete implementation of interface CSVWriter) -- this works:

```
new DeviceWriter(params) {
    ...
    CSVHeader headerWriter = new HeaderFactory().getHeader(params);
}
```

HeaderFactory (concrete class):

```
public CSVHeader getHeader(params) {
   //when debugging in StationWriter it doesn't even get to this point. 
   CSVHeader header; 
   if (something == true) {
       header = new TypeOneHeader(params);
    } else {
       header = new TypeTwoHeader(params);
    }
    return header;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of params? can it be `null`?

Comment: StationWriter.<init> means the StationWriter constructor

Comment: are you 100% sure that the given line is really line 98? The NPE comes from inside the constructor, but at the given line there is no object, that could be null.

Comment: The code you posted should be working. Can you post more code around the line 98?

Comment: @oers just as a pedantic note if `params` is some boxed value, like `Long` and `getHeader` accepts `long`, unboxing of `params == null` can cause NPE on exactly that 98th line.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an Eclipse issue. Can you post the full constructor for StationWriter? The code you posted looks like you're creating an anonymous inner class (there is `new StationWriter` where I'd expect to see `public StationWriter` or just `StationWriter` for a constructor.

Comment: @VictorSorokin thx :) you're right. I'm just used to seeing params as Strings or something like that.

Comment: Here's the list of params from the actual factory `SubSampleType subSampleType, int subSamplePeriod, boolean includeMetaDataHeader, Device device, String observatoryName, boolean breakOnSiteChange,
   boolean breakOnSamplePeriodChange, String stationName, TreeMap<Date, Device> deviceMap, List<Site> sites`; they can be null.

Comment: What type are subSamplePeriod, includeMetaDataHeader, includeMetaDataHeader,  breakOnSamplePeriodChange. Is any of those an Integer or Boolean respectively? (see victors comment to me)

Comment: @Victor Sorokin:  I think that's it.  subSample is an int in the original code, but then it was changed to Integer in the subsequent code.  So that explains why it doesn't work.  Now it can be null; previously it could only be an int value.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Working now.  Thanks!  I would post the answer but I don't have the reputation so I have to wait another 7 hours.

Comment: Why not let Victor post the answer, he's the one pointing you in the right direction. A generic answer would suffice for this issue on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found out in comments, issue was caused by unboxing of null `Integer`.

Comment: Augh.  Code evolution without Darwin's principles.  :)  So the principal for me to take away from this is that if the parameter may at some point in the future be passed in as a null boxed value, I should use a boxed type in the signature.

Comment: @GLaDOS well, better way is to have sufficient amount of unit tests to catch such things as soon as possible.

Comment: True. I neglected unit tests for this since the component under test integrates a lot of objects cached from data loaded from the db.  I would love to find an article that could help me learn to load fake data into cache so I don't have to use the db for tests.

Comment: @GLaDOS For this, first point is to try to code against interfaces, so you will be able to pass some stub implementation to your code being tested. Second point, if you need to pass some 3rd party type to your code being tested and that type isn't interface, you can try `Mockito` or similar unit-testing framework. Mockito is very cool for such things.